# Separate navigation structure from code in Android

Tags: android, design-patterns, data-structures

I would like to ask a question about the proper way to store navigation structure away from the java code in Android. I would like to store application structure in xml file in resources. The program would work only on the generated list.

Previously I parsed own XML to the list. The id of each item runs an appropriate code using invoking methods. However, it isn't too fast and programmer friendly.

So I decided to use an `enum` type. This not eliminate the possibility of entering an incorrect values in XML but it eliminates the possibility of making a typo in the code itself. Each element calls a method (with switch-case) that checks what type of item is pressed and if it enum is `APP_ITEM` then runs the appropriate program depending on the id (yet another magic string in XML).

Sample app structure:

```
"Main screen"
- Item that runs dialer
- Second item that carries to subscreen
    - Item one
    - Item two

"Second screen"
- Item that runs browser
- Awesome meter
```

Presented in XML:

```
<app_navigation>
    <screen name="Main screen">
        <item enum="APP_ITEM" id="dialer" name="Item that runs dialer"></item>
        <item name="Second item that carries to subscreen">
            <screen name="Some subscreen">
                <item enum="SOME_ITEM" name="Item one"></item>
                <item enum="SOME_ITEM" name="Item two"></item>
            </screen>
        </item>
    </screen>

    <screen name="Second screen">
        <item enum="APP_ITEM" id="browser" name="Item that runs browser"></item>
        <item enum="SOME_ITEM" name="Awesome meter"></item>
    </screen>
</app_navigation>
```

Is there any better way to separate navigation structure from code? I want to support app from API 8.